# loading php page with class in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have popup class in javascript and added all scripts in my html page that are required to display that popup. I am trying to load PHP page in that popup on submit button click of my form.

Popup is working fine for button like below (text from select.php is showing on popup box):

```
<a href="select.php" class="home-banner-button popup">Activate</a>
```

Now I have a form and on submit I have to redirect to PHP page depending on condition. And result should be display in popup.

I tried to load page with my popup class as below but its not showing the popup.

markup like below:

```
<form method="post" action="#"  onSubmit="return check();">
   <input type="text" id="textid" placeholder="Enter Here" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />                
</form>
```

Javasript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('.popup').colorbox({
        iframe: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
        fixed: true,
        innerWidth: 500,
        innerHeight: 180,
        scrolling: false
    });
});

function check() {
    var price = $('#textid').val();
    var new_value = price.replace(/\,/g, '');
    var lower_limit_value = 375;
    var upper_limit_value = 1712;

    if (new_value >= lower_limit_value && new_value <= upper_limit_value) {
        $(".popup").load("correct.php");
        return false;
    } else {
        $(".popup").load("incorrect.php");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I think I am using wrong syntax of this  `$(".popup").load("correct.php");`

I am not getting how to use that/how do I call a class(e.g .popup) in javascript with loading php page or other way of doing this.

or
How to use ajax in this case? Can ajax will help in such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using .colorbox() function directly as below. Its working fine now. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var price = $('#textid').val();
        var new_value = price.replace(/\,/g,'');
        var lower_limit_value = 375;
        var upper_limit_value = 1712;

    if (new_value>=lower_limit_value && new_value<=upper_limit_value) {

    $.colorbox({
href:"correct.php",
iframe:true, 
opacity:0.7, 
fixed:true, 
innerWidth:500, 
innerHeight:250, 
scrolling:false});
    return false;

    } else {

    $.colorbox({
href:"incorrect.php",
iframe:true, 
opacity:0.7, 
fixed:true, 
innerWidth:500, 
innerHeight:320, 
scrolling:false});  
    return false;

    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What error do you see in the browser console? I tried to run your code, I am able to show the content of a PHP file in the page using your code.

Make sure you have a div or some other element with a class "popup" attached to it. I had to add the following to your code to make it work.

```
<div class="popup"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to open a colorbox on clicking submit, as per the comment thread below. Here is something that works and opens a popup, with a page inside. This is not perfect, but does the job. You have to tweak the height.width and other properties to make it work properly. Try if this works.

Change your script to the following:

```
$(function () {
   //Removed the popup code from here. Made that conditional.
});

function check() {
    var price = $('#textid').val();
    var new_value = price.replace(/\,/g, '');
    var lower_limit_value = 375;
    var upper_limit_value = 1712;

    if (new_value >= lower_limit_value && new_value <= upper_limit_value) {
        $('.popup').colorbox({
          iframe: true,
          opacity: 0.7,
          fixed: true,
          height: 500,
          width: 180,
          scrolling: false,
          href: "correct.php",
          open: true
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.popup').colorbox({
          iframe: true,
          opacity: 0.7,
          fixed: true,
          height: 500,
          width: 180,
          scrolling: false,
          href: "incorrect.php",
          open: true
        });
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ Subrat Pattnaik: i tried by attaching class to div which is parent for that above form but its not working still. Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings, in the browser console, after you click the button?

Comment: yes, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined . this is in js file that i have used for entering only numeric text in text box. this only when i am including `$(".popup").load("correct.php");`. not getting when used `window.loaction("url"); ` instead of that. Is there any syntax mistake with `load` function?

Comment: there is .colorbox() function to make popup happen in my code. how do I use .colorbox() to load php page? Do you have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: Never used colorbox. However, I tried putting your complete code in my sandbox and created two dummy php files. I am able to show the content of php files in a div. They are showing properly, just below the form. So I think, your load syntax is correct. Ajax or non-ajax really depends on your implementation.

Comment: You are not getting the error when you use window.location("url"), because, you are being redirected to a different page. So the previous errors you were getting in the console are getting refreshed. That is the reason, you are not seeing any error in console.

Comment: i want to use popup to show php files. I tried to show them below form. .colorbox() i have used in javascript above in question.  `$('.popup').colorbox({..` I am not getting any way to show that in my popup:( Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Updated my answer, check the EDIT section. This is now opening a new popup with the requested file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75478/discussion-between-kiran-and-subrat-pattnaik).

Comment: Sorry.. I was away. Looks like you solved the problem.. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if DOM is being lost in jquery script for the function check. write it in `$(function)` and also I have a doubt that you do not have embed a area containing class .popup in your HTML page. Please check...it will be solved.

Comment: @ DevLakshman: I have included files required for .popup. thanks